# ParseError: Unexpected token with Gulpfile reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I am trying to create a very simple approach of `reactjs` components but I am getting this error for no reason.

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
SyntaxError: 
/home/junaid/letsVote/app/src/js/components/Feed.js:21
      <div>
      ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Setup is very simple, I would share my Gulpfile and everything so you have a clear view of what I am trying to do

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    connect = require("gulp-connect"),
    open = require("gulp-open"),
    browserify = require("gulp-browserify"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    port = process.env.port || 3031;

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  gulp.src("./app/src/js/main.js")
      .pipe(browserify({ transform: 'reactify' }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task("open", function() {
  var options = {
    url: "http://localhost:" + port
  };
  gulp.src("./app/index.html")
      .pipe(open("", options));
});

gulp.task("connect", function() {
  connect.server({
    root: "app",
    port: port,
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task("js", function() {
  gulp.src("./app/dist/**/*.js")
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task("html", function() {
  gulp.src("./app/*.html")
      .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("app/dist/js/*.js", ["js"]);
  gulp.watch("app/index.html", ["html"]);
  gulp.watch("app/src/js/**/*.js", ["browserify"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["browserify"]);
gulp.task("serve", ["browserify", "connect", "open", "watch"]);
```

this all above is my gulpfile through which i am dealing with reactfiles.

```
var React = require("react");
var ShowAddButton = require("./ShowAddButton");
var FeedForm = require("./FeedForm");
var FeedList = require("./FeedList");

var Feed = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    var FEED_ITEMS = [
      { key: "1", title: "Real Time data", description: "Firebase is cool", voteCount: 89},
      { key: "1", title: "Time data", description: "Life is cool", voteCount: 29},
      { key: "1", title: "Host Time data", description: "mochta is cool", voteCount: 9}
    ];
    return {
      items: FEED_ITEMS
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <ShowAddButton />
        </div>

        <FeedForm />

        <br />
        <br />

        <FeedList items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Feed
```

This is my Feed.js file on which I am getting error, I have tried every possible thing to resolve this issue but no solution is working at the moment, any help would be better, thanks.

my Package.json file is

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.11.1",
    "gulp-react": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-open": "^0.2.8",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.0",
    "reactify": "^0.14.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I should say, I don't know to build anything with gulphfile. but I build most of the reactjs projects using webpack. so I have also faced these parse errors with an unexpected token. so I advise you, if you use any loaders such as CSS or JS loaders, you must check the related rules for these loaders. because most of the parse errors will be made due to these loaders in webpack.i will hope this might be helpful for your problem!